# Sending special bash characters to a custom function

Tags: linux, bash, colors, prompt, ps1

I read this great article on customizing the bash prompt:

http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/21/customizing-your-bash-command-prompt/

I also read about using 256 colors in bash:

http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/20255

Now, here's what my .bashrc looks like:

```
# Extended 256 colors
ext-color() {
    echo -ne "\[\033[38;5;$1m\]$2\[\033[m\]"
}

# Set a fancy prompt
PS1="`ext-color 172 \u` in `ext-color 172 $(pwd)`"
```

This get's me really close to having an orange prompt, but the username isn't being printed. Instead it looks like this:

```
u in /home/dave
```

How do I modify this to print the username of the currently logged-in user? I mean like this:

```
dave in /home/dave
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler than you're making it out to be. When you run the command `ext-color 172 \u` (either as part of setting PS1 or on its own), the shell parses `\u`, removing what it thinks is an irrelevant `\`, before passing it to `ext-color` as `$2`. The solution is simple: enclose it in quotes before passing it to `ext-color`:

```
PS1="$(ext-color 172 '\u') in $(ext-color 172 '\w')"
```

(Note that I've also replaced the backquotes with `$( )`, used `\w` instead of `$(PWD)`, and quoted `'\w'` for the same reason as `'\u'`.)

Comment: Changed the accepted answer since this addresses what I was actually asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the approach that seems to work in the second part of the prompt, try e.g.:

```
PS1="`ext-color 172 $(whoami)` in `ext-color 172 $(pwd)`"
```

or even simpler:

```
PS1="`ext-color 172 $USER` in `ext-color 172 $(pwd)`"
```

or even nicer:

```
PS1="$(ext-color 172 "$USER") in $(ext-color 172 "$(pwd)")"
```

The last version won't cut off the part after a potential space in current directory because of the quotes around the `pwd` call.

---

**EDIT:** That won't update the working directory, as noted in the comment. I didn't even think of that since the question specifically asked about the user part (it's late here :-) ).

The easiest ("correct", "only") way is to just write

```
PS1='\[\033[38;5;172m\]\u\[\033[m\] in \[\033[38;5;172m\]\w\[\033[m\]'
```

and skip the function definition altogether.

---

**Expansion:** To get the `PS1` variable to dynamically expand function calls, use a backslash to hinder premature evaluation:

```
PS1="$(ext-color 172 "\$USER") in $(ext-color 172 "\$PWD")"
```

should work.

Comment: The first two seem to work. However `$PWD` doesn't change when I cd.

Comment: @davidkennedy85: Alright, I suspected that might be the case, but I wasn't sure. I'll update. EDIT: or you mean on all variants? Hmm, yeah, I can see why. I wonder how we can pass the `\w` to the external call... I didn't even look at this since your question specifically concerned the `\u` part :-)

Comment: Odd - calling `pwd` from the command line or even `echo $PWD` displays `/home/dave/Code` but the prompt is not changing.

Comment: @davidkennedy85: The `pwd` call in the `PS1` variable will only be made once when the `.bashrc` file is read, so it won't continuously be updated. The `\w` sequence is meant to take care of this as a "magic value" that gets interpreted by internal Bash logic.

Comment: That figures. I was just trying to be fancy. So are you saying it's impossible to send special bash characters to a custom function?

Comment: Hold on... it seems issuing `PS1=$(pwd)` from the command line works but not putting it in .bashrc.

Comment: @davidkennedy85: Well, in this case the `\w` sequence is only special since Bash interprets it specially in when it writes out the `PS1` value to the prompt. The `$()` or `\`\`` function calls are run when the `.bashrc` file is first run and then never again: if you prepend a backslash, as in e.g. `\$(pwd)`, it will work, since it will only be executed when `PS1` is called.

Comment: Aha! `PS1="$(ext-color 172 "$USER") in $(ext-color 172 "\$PWD")"` Good call on the backslash :)